# Graphing a histogram in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm trying to make a histogram that looks like this:

```
 1 - 5: ****
 6 - 10: ******
 11 - 15: **
 16 - 20: **********
 21 - 25: ***********
 26 - 31: ********
 31 - 35: ****
 36 - 41: *******
 41 - 45: ************
 46 - 50: *****************
```

Here is my code so far:

```
public static void graph (int[] arr) {
    for ( int i=0; i <= 50; i+=5) {
        System.out.println(i+" - " + ( i + 4 ) + " :" );
        for ( int num : arr) {
            if ( num >= i && num <= i + 4)
                System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my output:

```
                         0 - 4 :
                       **5 - 9 :
                        10 - 14 :
                       *15 - 19 :
                        20 - 24 :
                      *25 - 29 :
                       30 - 34 :
                      *35 - 39 :
                       40 - 44 :
                       45 - 49 :
                       50 - 54 :
```

Need some help fixing my code. I've been trying to figure this out for quite some time now. Also if anyone is kind enough to help please use java code that's not that advanced. I want to understand what I'm coding so I prefer for you all just to fix my code and not code anything new. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You call `println` before the inner loop. Change that to `print` so it doesn't end the line, allowing the `*` characters to be printing on the same line, then add a `println()` *after* the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void graph (int[] arr) {

          for ( int i=0; i <= 50; i+=5){
              System.out.print(i+" - " + ( i + 4 ) + " :" );
              for ( int num : arr) {
                  if ( num >= i && num <= i + 4)
                      System.out.print("*");

                  }
                  System.out.println();
              }
}
```

Output: (With `int[] array = {1, 3, 3, 6, 8, 9, 15, 20, 50};` as the array)

```
0 - 4 :***

5 - 9 :***

10 - 14 :

15 - 19 :*

20 - 24 :*

25 - 29 :

30 - 34 :

35 - 39 :

40 - 44 :

45 - 49 :

50 - 54 :*
```